# How to format an email 'From' header that contains a comma

Tags: email, email-headers

The standard way to format the 'From' email header is

```
From: John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
```

But what to do if there's a comma in the name?

```
From: John Doe, chief bottle washer <john.doe@example.com>
```

If I do that, my MTA automatically converts this into:

```
From: John@this.server.com, Doe@this.server.com, chief bottle washer <john.doe@example.com>
```

My first guess is to use double-quotes around the full name, but I can't find any official documentation confirming this and I'd like my emails to be readable by all email clients.

Comment: This question and the answers have a surprising number of negative votes. The information seems good. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 35):

To elaborate on the answer by @Fls'Zen, yes the proper method is to enclose the name in double-quotes.

From a practical point of view there's no harm in wrapping all names in double-quotes, just be sure to escape a double-quote if it appears in the display name `\"` (or just replace with a single-quote).  But if you want to be completely by the spec, you shouldn't use the double quotes if you don't have to.

For all the dense details, E-mail header fields are defined by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). The relevant section for multiple originators in the From header is [3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2), and the relevant sections for quoting delimiters is [3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.1) and [3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4).

Comment: Shouldn't you refer to RFC2822? Because RFC5322 isn't a propsed standard yet. It's still a draft.

Answer (score 5):

When the [following regular expression matches](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3), then an email display address must be quoted.

```
[^-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~\s]
```

For ASCII characters, this can be done by escaping any double quote characters with a backslash, and enclosing the string in double quotes.  For non-ASCII characters, the more complex [MIME escaping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) is required.

Comment: Whitespace characters are allowed. So this would be `[^-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&\'*+-/=?^_\`{|}~\\s]+` with `\s` being the white space character class.

Comment: And the second `-` is too much. Like this it includes all characters between `+` and `/`. So the complete regex working for me is: `[^-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_\`{|}~\\s]+` The `'` only needs to be escaped when you enclose the string with it. So enclosing in `"` this would be correct: `[^-A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~\\s]+`

Comment: Thank you, I incorporated your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

E-mail header fields are defined by [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). The relevant section for multiple originators in the `From` header is [3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2). The relevant sections for quoting delimiters is [3.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.1) and [3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4).

Comment: If I'm interpreting this RFC correctly (and these things are by no means human readable), then the solution is to enclose in double quotes From: "John Doe, chief bottle washer" <john.doe@example.com> ???

Comment: Furthermore, is there any harm in wrapping all names in double quotes, regardless of whether a comma (or other illegal character) is present?

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way. Using double quotes all the time doesn't hurt anything, just make sure to escape a double-quote if it appears in the display name.